# Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Error 404

Tags: php, html

When I press the login button, it gives me an object not found error 404 and that the URL is not correct. I have made a file with the php code and I have put the php code in the html file of the Login form.

Update: I tried to change the path, but now I get a message Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

public/actions/login.php

```
    <?php

use Hotel\User;

// Boot application
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../boot/boot.php';

//Return to home page if not a post request
if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post') {
    header('Location: /');

    return;
}

// If there is already logged in user, return to main page
if (!empty(User::getCurrentUserId())) {
    header('Location: /');    
    
    return;
}

//Verify user
$user = new User();
try {
    if (!$user->verify($_REQUEST['email'], $_REQUEST['password'])) {
        header('Location: /public/login.php?error=Could not verify user');

        return;
    }
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $ex) {
    header('Location: /public/login.php?error=No User exists with the given email');

    return;
}

// Create token as cookie for user for 30 days
$userInfo = $user->getByEmail($_REQUEST['email']);
$token = $user->getUserToken($userInfo['user_id']);
setcookie('user_token', $token, time() *60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/');

// Return to home page
header('Location: /public/landing_page.php');

?>
```

When i press login dont put me to public/actions/login.php
public/login.php

```
    <?php

    require __DIR__.'/../boot/boot.php';

    use app\Hotel\User;
    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf8">
        </head>
    <body>
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <p class="main-logo">Hotels</p>
                    <div class="primary-menu text-right">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">
                                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                                Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
                    <aside class="hotel-register">
                        <form method="post" action="/actions/login.php">
                                <?php if (!empty($_GET['error'])) { ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-styled-left">Register Error</div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Your Email Adress</label>
                                <input id="email" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" name="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="formPassword">Your Password:</label>
                                <input id="formPassword" value="" type="password" placeholder="Your password" name="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn_landing btn-brick" type="submit" value="login">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </aside>
                <footer class="footer">
                    <p>(c) Copyright CollegeLink 2020</p>
                </footer>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
                <link href="\assets\css\register.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure `action="/actions/login.php"` correct?

Comment: @kampit which is correct?? You think the path is wrong?

Comment: looks like your url is public/actions/login.php

Comment: Update: I changed the Path of the action without the " " and when I clicked login it took me to apache's localhost with the Project folder. I did print_r to see if user exists and user exists.